# How can I use eclipse keymaps in visual studio?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, keymap

I have been an eclipse user, and when I switched to intelliJ I simply used the eclipse keymap in intellij.

Now in my work, i need to use Visual Studio 2019. I noticed that it doesn't have eclipse mapping saved.. So what can I do? Is there anyway for me to get eclipse keymaps other than setting the hotkeys I use one by one? Or is there some way for me to export my intelliJ mapping to a format that visual studio understands?

(I'm using visual studio, not visual studio code)

Comment: I want to know how to do that, too. Kinda surprising VS doesn't support such a basic feature (import/export key bindings). I also don't see any public plugin available that would do such bindings. What a sad state of affairs. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an "Eclipse Keymap" extension you can install. As far as I can tell, it doesn't replace all VSC shortcuts and not everything eclipse does is available but it's a good first step